# Laravel routes giving 404 error on Apache on AWS Amazon Linux

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess, httpd.conf, custom-error-pages

I am trying to deploy a Laravel application to AWS EC2 instance which is running on Amazon Linux 2. I have the following configuration in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

```
# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myfolder/public

#ServerName site.domain.com

<Directory /var/www/html/myfolder/public>
  Options FollowSymLinks Indexes MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Require all granted
  allow from all
</Directory>
```

and in the `.htaccess` in the root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I access the site using `http://3.xxx.xxx.xxx/myfolder/login`, but this is giving 404 error. It is the Laravel 404 and I am not sure what else I need to do in the server for accessing the application. Everything is working fine in local. It will be very much helpful if someone can point me in the right direction.

It is the Laravel 404 is shown. Not the default one.

Comment: if your path is `/var/www/html/myfolder/public`, then any URL is going to be without `myfolder`, so `http://3.xxx.xxx.xxx/myfolder/login` should be `http://3.xxx.xxx.xxx/login` unless you have explicity specified your route is `myfolder/login`, but without you sharing the routes, it is hard to know

Comment: since you are hosting the project in a subfolder, you need to add ``RewriteBase /myfolder`` after the ``RewriteEngine On`` in the ``.htaccess`` file also, add an alias ``Alias /var/www/html/myfolder /var/www/html/myfolder/public`` within the ``<Directory /var/www/html/myfolder/public>`` block in config file.